# How to initiate WebViewController in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, default-constructor, dart-null-safety

I was trying to declare a variable in class level as below:

WebViewController _webViewController = WebViewController();

sothat I can reuse that in other functions.But for nullsafety issue I tried to initialize it, but showing **doesn’t have a default constructor**.I tried also like,

```
 WebViewController _webViewController ; (it shows to add late modifier)
```

or

```
WebViewController _webViewController = null; (null can not be assigned)
```

how should I declare ?

Comment: This depends on the package that you are using. Which one are u using ?

Comment: 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'; (webview_flutter: ^1.0.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs of [WebViewController](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html), you can see that it says,

> A WebViewController instance can be obtained by setting the WebView.onWebViewCreated callback for a WebView widget.

Now if we check the docs for [onWebViewCreated](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebView/onWebViewCreated.html), we see that it is of type [WebViewCreatedCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewCreatedCallback.html), which provides an instance of `WebViewController` as it's parameter in the callback you provide.

So, first

```
// Make it late since we can't create an instance by ourselves
late WebViewController _webViewController;
```

Then, in your build method where you are using the widget,

```
WebView(
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    // We are getting an instance of the controller in the callback
    // So we take it assign it our late variable value
    _webViewController = controller,
  },
  .....
```

Now, you can use your `_webViewController` anywhere in your code.

Comment: This does not seem to be true. I get the error "has not been initialized" if I try to use it in init.

Comment: Hi, which init are you talking about ? Also since we only get a instance of the controller one the webview is ready, you should have a nullable type for the controller variable.
From your error, it might be that you are just accessing it even before the webview has been created.